Who is "K·K" in Genshin Impact?
I see the full-body standing drawing of Traveler below:

English version:

"Don't lose faith in that which you have lost. In this new world, you will never be alone. Where you leave your footprints, and where you have yet to stride — your new world will unfold before you."
"Welcome to a new world."
—— K·K

So who is K·K? I had never seen him in the game except in the drawing. As the traveler is Descender, K·K should not be less than him. And the sentence "Welcome to the world" (Chinese version) shows that K·K's status is very high. Is he the creator of the world?

I don't think there's a definitive answer to this, it's just theories in the whole HoYoverse as this name also appears in Honkai. You can read a bit about it in this article: https://gamerant.com/genshin-impact-character-kk-identity-unknown/.

Could be like the Creator that mention in Traveler story and the one he probaly fogot.
